# Tab control mouse over

Tags: wpf

I am trying to create a tab control with a style like Google's kitchen sink example.
When the mouse goes over a tab i want to be able to change its color and when i click that tab its content background color changes to match and the tab changes. However, if you don't click the tab and the mouse moves i want it to go back to its original color. I want the tabs to be different colors.

What i have right now is when i hover over the intro tab content "Content for intro"

that content font changes to red. I had to change it to foreground so i could see that it was working. Keep in mind i am very new to xaml and wpf. I am trying to teach myself and the book i have has a very small section on styles.

Here is Google's kitchen sin example hat i am trying to achieve.
http://gwt.google.com/samples/KitchenSink/KitchenSink.html

Any help is much appreciated.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="mouseOverColor"
            Color="Red" />
        <Style x:Key="myStyle" TargetType="TabItem">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                                     Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                        Value="{StaticResource mouseOverColor}" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TabControl  Background="AliceBlue"  Grid.Column="1"
             Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="92,40,37,80"
             Grid.Row="2">
            <TabItem  Header="Intro" >
                <TabItem Style="{StaticResource myStyle}" >
                    Content for intro
                </TabItem>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Widgets">
                Content for widget
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Panels">
                content for panel
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I suspect you shouldn't have the TabItem referencing your style nested within the Intro TabItem. Instead, put the `Style={...}` attribute after the `Header="Intro"` attribute, within the same TabItem tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit complex because the background of the selected tab is colourless by default, so you need to override the control template. It is best to modify the default style so you do not need to start over, which in any case is quite verbose:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="TabItemControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
            <Border.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Background}" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Background}" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Border.Style>
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderStringFormat}" ContentSource="Header" HorizontalAlignment="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False"/>
                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="#FF3C7FB1"/>
        </MultiTrigger>
        <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Bottom">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="Bd" Value="1,0,1,1"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Left">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="Bd" Value="1,1,0,1"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Right">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="Bd" Value="0,1,1,1"/>
        </Trigger>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                <Condition Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Top"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-2,-2,-2,-1"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="Content" Value="0,0,0,1"/>
        </MultiTrigger>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                <Condition Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Bottom"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-2,-1,-2,-2"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="Content" Value="0,1,0,0"/>
        </MultiTrigger>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                <Condition Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Left"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-2,-2,-1,-2"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="Content" Value="0,0,1,0"/>
        </MultiTrigger>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                <Condition Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Right"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-1,-2,-2,-2"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="Content" Value="1,0,0,0"/>
        </MultiTrigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="#FFF4F4F4"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="#FFC9C7BA"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

If you want to change the default colour, change the setter on the border which specifies that the background should be grey.

Also to make the content part the same colour as the tab an additional binding in the TabControl is needed. Further this control template needs to be applied to the items, either via an automatic style or direct reference:

```
<TabControl x:Name="MyControl" Height="200"
            Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=SelectedItem.Background}">
    <TabItem Header="tab1" Background="Red"   Template="{DynamicResource TabItemControlTemplate}"/>
    <TabItem Header="tab2" Background="Green" Template="{DynamicResource TabItemControlTemplate}"/>
    <TabItem Header="tab3" Background="Blue" Template="{DynamicResource TabItemControlTemplate}"/>
</TabControl>
```

First tab selected, mouse over last tab:
[image: Screenshot]

---

Usage annotation:

```
<Window ...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="TabItemControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            ...
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <!-- You can reference the template anywhere inside the visual tree
             of the Window if it has been declared in the Resources of the
             window, most XML elemnts that are children of the Window element
             are inside its visual tree -->
        <TabControl ...>
            <TabItem Template="{StaticResource TabItemControlTemplate}" .../>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Can i get the full code with it all together? not sure what i need before the first part of the code to get it to work? i pasted the code and it wouldnt work. Do i need something like windows.resources first?

Comment: That is the full code, you should not need anything else. Just place the template in some `Resources`. *"it wouldnt work"* is awfully precise, how does it not work?

Comment: what i mean is i copied the code and i pasted it into y project but what goes before - <ControlTemplate x:Key="TabItemControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">?

Comment: i placed it in between <Window.Resources> </Window.Resources> but its now a blank form

Comment: can i do this in expression blend?

Comment: If you see something with the `x:Key` property you can assume it to be a resource, that means you should place it in a resource dictionary; any reasource dictionary which is at a higher level than where it is used, `Window.Resources` would be appripriate in this case. If you still have trouble with this you should read the following: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750613.aspx

Comment: I wrote my last comment while you posted the recent two; if you get a blank form that is rather weird. It does not really matter if you use Blend or not, Blend just has a better visualization that's all.

Comment: where does the tab control code go? before the first code or after? sorry i am very new to xaml

Comment: I added some annotations, also make sure to read the article i linked to.

Comment: its blank becuase i dont know wher to put the tabcontrol code at in with the other code.. caan you help me?

Comment: hey, how did you learn all of this? is here a good book i can get?

Comment: MSDN is all you need, if you have VS 2010 you can put the cursor on a method/class/property/whatever and hit F1 and it will bring you to the right page on the documentation, further there are lots of `Overview` articles which are quite perfect, e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx , http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: wow, i got it to work. thank you... i just want to learn how to do this myself. thats alot to take in. thats alot of code..

Comment: Once you have the basics (which for the most part can be found in the overviews i mentioned) it's mostly learning-by-doing and trial-and-error. If you program a lot of XAML you will gather a lot of knowledge about what can be done what cannot be done in the system.

Comment: ok, there is a lot to take in! i will look over those articles. i need to learn triggers and events. thank you so much!

Comment: you did an excellent job  in helping me i wish i could give you more points or something. I liked the picture of the tabs you provided. thank you so much